# prevProps and props are the same

Tags: reactjs

When I use componentDidUpdate to compare prevProps or prevState, I got the same thing as my current props or state.

I have searched about it and found that we should use state and props in an immutability way and I've done it already. But the issue hasn't been resolved.

So is there anything that may cause this issue?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import Counters from "./components/counters";
// import Table from './components/table';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("App - constructor");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("App - componentDidMount");
  }

  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
      { id: 2, value: 1 },
      { id: 3, value: 2 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 },
    ],
  };

  resetHandler = () => {
    let counters = [...this.state.counters];
    let newCounters = counters.map((counter) => {
      counter.value = 0;
      return counter;
    });
    this.setState({ counters: newCounters });
  };

  deleteHandler = (id) => {
    let counters = [...this.state.counters];
    let newCounters = counters.filter((counter) => counter.id !== id);
    this.setState({ counters: newCounters });
  };

  incrementHandler = (id) => {
    let counters = [...this.state.counters];
    let newCounters = counters.map((counter) => {
      if (counter.id === id) {
        counter.value = counter.value + 1;
      }
      return counter;
    });
    this.setState({ counters: newCounters });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("prevProps", prevProps);
    console.log("prevState", prevState);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("App - render");
    return (
      <>
        <NavBar
          totalCounters={this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).length}
        />
        <main className="container">
          <Counters
            onReset={this.resetHandler}
            onIncrement={this.incrementHandler}
            onDelete={this.deleteHandler}
            counters={this.state.counters}
          />
        </main>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is counters :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './counter'

class Counters extends Component {
  
  render() { 
    console.log("counters - render")
    const { onReset, counters, onDelete, onIncrement} = {...this.props}
    return ( 
      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2" onClick={onReset}>Reset</button>
        {counters.map( counter => 
          <Counter key={counter.id} 
            counter={counter}
            onDelete={onDelete}
            onIncrement={onIncrement} />)}
      </div>
     );
  }
}
 
export default Counters;
```

This is counter:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {

  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { value } = {...this.props.counter}
    return value === 0 ? 'zero' : value
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter.id)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2">Increment</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.counter.id)} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2">Delete</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 
export default Counter;
```

Comment: How did you check whether prev props, state are same as the current props, state ?

Comment: How do you use `onReset` in `Counters` component?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika I check it on the console.

Comment: @lazy.lizard I've edited the post and put the code

Comment: Well I see no reason in `state` shallow copy you create on every function and there's nothing seems to be wrong in your code.

Comment: @lazy.lizard I see. every time I did Update, I check prevState and it is the same as the current state. I don't know what is going on...

Comment: Try this out: `resetHandler = () => {         const newCounters = this.state.counters.map(({id}) => ({             id,             value: 0          }));         this.setState({ counters: newCounters });     };`

Comment: @lazy.lizard Can you please explain why it solve the OP's issue ? I checked it locally, this doesn't seem to be an issue on `resetHandler` method. Becuase, it doesn't have any dependency on `increamentHandler` which causes the issue as OP mentioned above.

Comment: I just wanted to know out if `NavBar` receives a new value after reset.